# GET request and updating post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, get, crud

I have a Post model, and I'm writing the portion of the application that can edit (update) a post.

The code works as follows:

```
def update
  @post = params[:post]
  old_post = Post.find(params[:id]
  old_post.update_attributes(:title => @post['title'], :content => @post['content'], :image_link => @post['image_link'])
  old_post.save!
  redirect_to old_post
end
```

The problem with this code, however, is that when the content goes long, the request fails because the length of the URI is too long. Changing webservers doesn't fix this as the string is far too long. Is there a way I can do this using POST to prevent the length limit?

Comment: By default the update method in your controller `(PostsController#update)` should be using `PUT` (or Patch depending on your rails version) but certainly **NOT** `GET`. Double check that you didn't manually changes the Http Verb for that action in your routes.rb

Comment: I did not. I left the routes as default. Even so, it gives me a URI too long error.

Comment: Can you capture the headers from the API call and edit your question with them?

Comment: What is your edit view code, specifically the form that submits to this action? Have you changed that from the default?